# Oracle Linux 6 Looking for cmd or way to correlate BUS:Device.Function to physical slot

Tags: oracle-linux, dmidecode

On Oracle Linux 7

```
[root@host ~]# uname -a
Linux host 4.1.12-61.1.18.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Fri Nov 4 15:48:30 PDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can use

```
[root@host ~]# dmidecode -V
3.0
[root@host ~]# dmidecode -t slot | grep -E "Designation|Usage|Bus Address"
        Designation: PCIE0
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: ffff:13:00.0
        Designation: PCIE1
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: ffff:21:00.0
        Designation: PCIE2
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: ffff:2f:00.0
        Designation: PCIE3
        Current Usage: Available
        Designation: PCIE4
        Current Usage: Available
        Designation: PCIE5
        Current Usage: Available
```

On Oracle Linux 6

```
[root@host ~]# uname -a
Linux host 3.8.13-68.3.4.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Tue Jul 14 15:03:36 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmidecode` is version 2.12

```
[root@host ~]# dmidecode -V
2.12
```

which does not list the Bus Address

```
[root@host ~]# dmidecode -t slot | grep -E "Designation|Usage|Bus Address"
        Designation: PCIExp SLOT0
        Current Usage: In Use
        Designation: PCIExp SLOT1
        Current Usage: Available
        Designation: PCIExp SLOT2
        Current Usage: Available
```

I tried `lshw` but that does not give correct info.

Any other ideas (besides upgrade to Oracle Linux 7)?

Comment: If you can't upgrade, you can always compile the new version of `dmidecode` yourself from source for Oracle Linux 6. But maybe upgrading is simpler...

Answer (score 0):

I installed Oracle Linux 6 to try to reproduce your problem. First of all, it does list Bus Addresses in my setup:

The `/etc/os-release` file (truncated):

```
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="6.10"
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux oracle6.local 4.1.12-124.28.5.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Jun 20 11:57:41 PDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `dmidecode -V`:

```
2.12
```

Output of `dmidecode -t slot | grep -E "Designation|Usage|Bus Address"`:

```
        Designation: ISA Slot J8
        Current Usage: Unknown
        Bus Address: 00ff:ff:1f.7
        Designation: ISA Slot J9
        Current Usage: Unknown
        Bus Address: 00ff:ff:1f.7
        Designation: ISA Slot J10
        Current Usage: Unknown
        Bus Address: 00ff:ff:1f.7
        Designation: PCI Slot J11
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: 0000:00:0f.0
        Designation: PCI Slot J12
        Current Usage: Available
        Bus Address: 0000:00:10.0
        Designation: PCI Slot J13
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: 0000:00:11.0
        Designation: PCI Slot J14
        Current Usage: Available
        Bus Address: 0000:00:12.0
```

Apparently, in your case it doesn't list the bus addresses. So to compile the lastest `dmidecode`, I did:

```
yum groupinstall Development
cd
wget "http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/dmidecode/dmidecode-3.2.tar.xz"
tar -xvf dmidecode-3.2.tar.xz
cd dmidecode-3.2
make && make install
```

To check the version, I ran `/usr/local/sbin/dmidecode -V` which gave:

```
3.2
```

And I repeated your command `/usr/local/sbin/dmidecode -t slot | grep -E "Designation|Usage|Bus Address"`:

```
        Designation: ISA Slot J8
        Current Usage: Unknown
        Bus Address: 00ff:ff:1f.7
        Designation: ISA Slot J9
        Current Usage: Unknown
        Bus Address: 00ff:ff:1f.7
        Designation: ISA Slot J10
        Current Usage: Unknown
        Bus Address: 00ff:ff:1f.7
        Designation: PCI Slot J11
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: 0000:00:0f.0
        Designation: PCI Slot J12
        Current Usage: Available
        Bus Address: 0000:00:10.0
        Designation: PCI Slot J13
        Current Usage: In Use
        Bus Address: 0000:00:11.0
        Designation: PCI Slot J14
        Current Usage: Available
        Bus Address: 0000:00:12.0
```

...which in my case gave the exact same output. But your mileage may vary of course, please let us know if the above worked for you.